# how to import product from csv with multiple images and how am I supposed to skip the invalid links while importing products in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, import, hyperlink, product

I am developing an e-commerce site with WordPress using woo-commerce. I want to import products from a custom PHP website(700+ products) to woo-commerce.

I know how to import and export with the CSV format and all but there is an issue, which is

some products have 1 to 3 images and some products have 5 to 6 images so in the image column some products have invalid image link and due to that, the product is not imported.

so my question is how to import products from CSV files with multiple images where some image links do not exist.

csv file sample - [Download Sample CSV](http://%20https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/702881642649354300/706109707743395860/MASTER_LIST3_-_Copy.csv)

in the above CSV file, you will see an image column where every product has 3 image links but not all product links are valid, some products have all 3 valid links and some have only 1 valid and 2 invalid links. so how am I supposed to skip the invalid links while importing products?

pls help me

thank you